# numba TypingError with complex numpy array and native data types

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I have a function that deals with complex data type and I am using `numba` for faster processing. I declare a zero array using `numpy`, with complex data type, to be filled in later in the function. But while running `numba` is not able to overload the zero generating function. To reproduce the error I have provided an MWE.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def my_func(idx):
    a = np.zeros((10, 5), dtype=complex)
    a[idx] = 10
    return a

my_func(4)
```

The following error is shown where the array `a` is being initialized.

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)

No implementation of function Function(<built-in function zeros>) found for signature:
zeros(Tuple(Literal[int](10), Literal[int](5)), dtype=Function(<class 'complex'>))
There are 2 candidate implementations:

 Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'zeros': File: numba\core\typing\npydecl.py: Line 511.
    With argument(s): '(UniTuple(int64 x 2), dtype=Function(<class 'complex'>))':
   No match.
```

I am assuming this has got to do with the data type of the variable `a` (I need it to be complex). How can I go about this error?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I suppose that you can rewrite this so that `my_func` operates inplace on an argument `a`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, this is just an example. The actual function is much more involved and it would be difficult to make an inplace replacement for the function

Comment: I take your point, but in some sense you are trying to implement functionality that one would want to be in `numba`.

Comment: Also, it seems that replacing `complex` with `np.complex64` or `np.complex128` works, while other choices I tried do not.

Comment: Presumably, this corresponds to a pair of 32-bit floats and 64-bit floats.

Comment: `nb.complex128` (same as `nb.c16`) and `nb.complex64` (same as `nb.c8`) also work.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with complex numbers. If you specified `a = np.zeros((10, 5), dtype=int)`, you'd run into the same problem.

While `numpy` takes python native data types `int`, `float` and `complex` and treats them as `np.int32`, `np.float64` and `np.complex128`, `numba` doesn't do that by itself however.

So whenever you specify data types inside jitted functions, you either use `numpy` data types:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def my_func(idx):
    a = np.zeros((10, 5), dtype=np.complex128)
    a[idx] = 10
    return a

my_func(4)
```

Or you use `numba` data types either via direct import:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, complex128

@njit
def my_func(idx):
    a = np.zeros((10, 5), dtype=complex128)
    a[idx] = 10
    return a

my_func(4)
```

or via `types`:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, types

@njit
def my_func(idx):
    a = np.zeros((10, 5), dtype=types.complex128)
    a[idx] = 10
    return a

my_func(4)
```

To my knowledge, it really doesn't make a difference, which one of these options you use. [Here](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html#signature-specifications) is the relevant part of the numba documentation.